# Shut Down Windows 7 Using Voice Control?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, voice-command

Is there a way to shut down Windows 7 using voice control and only a single command.  Windows 7 does provide voice control shutdown, but you have to say: start > show numbers > 8
then it will shutdown.

Any simple direct command to do that?

Comment: I'm surprised that opening the start menu and then saying "Shut Down" doesn't do the trick.

Comment: in windows 7 it writes 'shut down' in the run box.

Answer (score 1):

Make program called "source" which runs normal shutdown, then you just have to say the words "open source" and Windows will automatically shut itself down.

Comment: The naming of that is so much win.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the speech recognition program Dragon NaturallySpeaking for that purpose: http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4595/~/commands-for-shutting-down-microsoft-windows-using-dragon-naturallyspeaking

> The following are some of the commands that can be used to shutdown or restart Windows while using Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

```
Shut down Windows.
Shut down Windows now.
Shut down the computer.
Shut down the computer now.
Shut down the computer immediately.
Restart Windows.
Restart Windows now.
Restart Windows immediately.
Restart the computer.
Restart the computer now.
Restart the computer immediately.
```

> When issuing commands like “shutdown the computer” or “restart the computer”, the user is taken to the last screen of the shutdown/ restart process, but the operation is not completed and the process needs user input to finish. We recommend saying “shutdown/ restart Windows immediately”. These commands will shutdown or restart the computer properly.